# Cambiar fuente de página web en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

me descargué una plantilla en html para empezar, pero quiero saber como le cambio la fuente, tengo el archivo "ttf" y "woff"
Lo malo es que ya tiene unas fuentes instaladas en el style, y tendria que pasar todo el estilo para que vean como lo tiene.
Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo **CSS** busca la regla **font-family**.

En caso de que el archivo CSS sea muy grande, puedes utilizar el buscador que viene integrado en tu editor de código, por ejemplo, en *VISUAL ESTUDIO CODE* es **CTRL + F**, en ese cuadro escribes **font-family** y eliminas todas las coincidencias, ahora podrás definir tus propias fuentes.

Para definir tus propias fuentes en el css los puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
@font-face 
    font-family: NOMBRE_DE_TU_FUENTE
    src: url('../libs/Fuentes/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf') //RUTA
```

Ahora podrás usarla con el nombre de que hayas definido en NOMBRE_DE_TU_FUENTE

Suerte.

Comment: invocar una fuente por el archivo ttf funciona así?

Comment: Donde pongo lo que puse en "NOMBRE_DE_LA_FUENTE?

Comment: en **font-family** . Por ejemplo:

h1{
font-family: "NOMBRE_DE_LA_FUENTE;
}

Comment: hasta donde se, los ttf se deben transformar en Open Wen Font format para poder hacer lo que te indican en esta respuesta @MerloST98

Comment: Como se haría eso?

Comment: Oh, no. Solo debes hacerlo como te expliqué. 
Eh aqui, informacion oficial:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: No me funciona.

Comment: @MerloST98 transforma tu fuente como te indico en el propio enlace que te pasan indica el formato que debe tener

Comment: Los tengo en .tff y .woff

Comment: Recuerda referenciar correctamente el la ubicación de tu fuente. Usa el inspector de google y en la pestaña NETWORK  apareceran todos los recursos que usa tu pagina web(imagenes, librerias, etc) ahi debe aparecer la fuente que estas cargando, por el contrario si aparece en rojo significa que no estas haciendo una referencia correcta.

Comment: La plantilla que descargue tiene un archivo que se llama font-awesome.css, tiene algo que ver?

Comment: no, esos son iconos.

Comment: Ahí puse una imagen de como se me ve

Comment: Es justo lo que te dije. Puedes posicionar el puntero encima de esa referencia en rojo y te mostrara una ruta. Verifica y compara si esa es la ruta en la que guardaste tu fuente.

Comment: Ahí está, pero se ve muy chiquita, y eso que puse en h1

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar la fuente de la página, hay algunas por defecto: Times New Roman, Arial y Courier New...
Para cambiar en el propio documento de html se podría hacer de esta forma:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body{
    font-family: "Arial"; 
    }
    </style
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Hola</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si tienes un archivo con el formato ttf o woff pues tendrías que modificarlo así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Nombre de la fuente";
    src: url("archivo-con-la-fuente.woff");
    }
    body {
    font-family: "Nombre de la fuente";
    }
    </style
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Hola</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No me funciona, borre mis fuentes y todo, puse eso y todo, y me aparece la letra predeterminada

Comment: Enséñame el código